# returning ArrayList from a method

Tags: java, arraylist

I am having problems returning the arraylist from this method.The method is supposed to check the given insurance type with the stored insurance type.If it matches,then that element is to be deleted and rest of them are to be displayed.

Please suggest the syntax for returning the arraylist here

```
public ArrayList<Insurance> retrieveDetails(String insType){

  Iterator<Insurance> itr=insurancelist.iterator();

  while(itr.hasNext()) {
    Insurance c=itr.next();

  if(c.getInsuranceType().equals(insType)) {
    insurancelist.remove(c);

}
else
    System.out.println(c);


}
```

Comment: This won't even compile - you have unbalanced {}

Comment: you should add return statement

Comment: can u please suggest the syntax for returning the arraylist

Comment: Skip the else part. Print each insurance in the list and then return it. Also please do take care of the braces.

Comment: Are you seriously coming here to ask how to return something from a method?? If you need someone to suggest how to do one of the most basic things possible then you are going to have a rough time getting anywhere

Comment: Please do state what error you are getting.

Comment: its returning the arraylist...but like this [com.Insurance@2a139a55, com.Insurance@15db9742, com.Insurance@6d06d69c]

Comment: @redFIVE I just plainly asked because i am very new at this..You dont have to show your superiority here.i am learning..

Comment: Yes but there are millions of site out there that have umpteen java tutorials. Being new to programming doesn't excuse you from doing research on your own first

Comment: Do you have any problem if i ask something here @redFIVE..or you dont have any work to do..

Comment: Google, `return statement java`. You're welcome

Comment: thanks you are truly a god at programming...please mind your own business from next time

Comment: Though redFIVE is certainly being a little combative here, his point is correct. SO is a site "for professional and enthusiast programmers", which implies at least a little bit of technical know-how. That's not to say we don't welcome beginners, but we do expect at least a little research to be done before you ask a question. Please keep this in mind for the next time.

Comment: Thanks @Mage Xy  ..FYI..its not that i did not research.But i was not getting the desired output from the program.Someone did suggest some good changes.I have seen more stupid questions asked here,And it was not about the return statement.I was unable to figure out the problem.I wont visit this site again to disturb the "sanctity' of "professional and enthusiast programmers".

Comment: @Jason If that's what you decide, fine, we certainly can't stop you. But I wouldn't write off the entire site due to a bad experience with one user.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're seeing:

> [com.Insurance@2a139a55, com.Insurance@15db9742, com.Insurance@6d06d69c]

Is that the Insurance class doesn't have a `toString()` method. So it's using the default `toString()` method from Object.

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

If you want it to make a little more sense when you print the Insurance objects you'll want to create a method in Insurance.java that looks something like this, assuming you have an insuranceType String and a policyID value as class variables:

```
public String toString() {
    return this.policyID+": "+this.insuranceType;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is what you have:

```
enum InsuranceType {}

interface Insurance {
    InsuranceType getType()
}
```

You have two straightforward options here:
  1. Use an iterator on the list and remove elements as you go.
  2. Loop over the list, find all elements you want to remove, then remove them after iterating.

```
public List<Insurance> retrieveDetais(List<Insurance> insurances, InsuranceType type) {
    List<Insurance> toRemove = new ArrayList<Insurance>();
    for (Insurance i : insurances) {
        if (i.getInsuranceType().equals(insuranceType)) {
            toRemove.add(i);
        }
    }
    for (Insurance i : toRemove) {
        insurances.remove(i);
    }
    return insurances;
}
```

You can always make this more generic or go the iterator route:

```
public List<Insurance> removeInsuranceType(List<Insurance> insurances, InsuranceType type) {
    Iterator<Insurance> iter = insurances.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Insurance i = iter.next();
        if (i.getType() == type) {
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
    return insurances;
}
```